# JavaFX dialog box text field not binding text entered inside it

Tags: javafx, modal-dialog

i have a dialog box in javafx and it accepts some username and password and hostname to create a connection.
But the Textfield  values are not appearing in back end .

```
private void popupCredentials(){

    final Stage dialog = new Stage();
    dialog.setTitle("Credentials");
    dialog.initModality(Modality.NONE);
    dialog.initOwner((Stage) tabpane.getScene().getWindow());
    TextField textField = new TextField();
    PasswordField passwordField = new PasswordField();
    TextField textField1 = new TextField();
    Label label2 = new Label("Enter Hostname");
    label2.setFont(Font.font(null, FontWeight.BOLD, 14));
    Label label = new Label("Enter Username");
    label.setFont(Font.font(null, FontWeight.BOLD, 14));
    Label label1 = new Label("Enter Password");
    label1.setFont(Font.font(null, FontWeight.BOLD, 14));
    Button button = new Button ("OK");
    button.setFont(Font.font(null, FontWeight.BOLD, 14));
    button.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: black;");
    VBox vBox = new VBox(4);
    VBox vBox1 = new VBox(1);
    vBox1.getChildren().addAll(label,textField,label1,passwordField,label2,textField1);
    vBox1.getChildren().add(button);
    final String hostIP = textField1.getText();
    final String userName = textField.getText();
    final String password = passwordField.getText();
    System.out.println(hostIP+"=="+userName+"=="+password);
    button.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED,
            new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent e) {
                            isSShConnected = sshManager.connect(hostIP, userName, password);
                            isSFTPConnected = sftpManager.connect(hostIP, userName, password);
                    if(isSFTPConnected && isSShConnected){
                        System.out.println("Connected");
                    }
                }
            });

    HBox hBox = new HBox(2);
    hBox.getChildren().addAll(vBox,vBox1);
    hBox.setPadding(new Insets(15, 12, 15, 12));
    hBox.setSpacing(10);
    Scene dialogScene = new Scene(hBox, 200,180);
    dialogScene.getStylesheets().add("/css/Style.css");
    dialog.setScene(dialogScene);
    dialog.show();
}
```

The Line where in print the hostname , username and password , is always comming blank and i am not able to figure out the issue here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You read the text from the `TextField`s before the scene is shown (`dialog.show();`) which results in the empty `String` being read from each of the `TextField`s. You need to read the text after the user submits the input, i.e. in the `EventHandler` for the `Button` event. You should use the `onAction` event instead btw.

```
final TextField textField = new TextField();
final PasswordField passwordField = new PasswordField();
final TextField textField1 = new TextField();

...

button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            String hostIP = textField1.getText();
            String userName = textField.getText();
            String password = passwordField.getText();

            isSShConnected = sshManager.connect(hostIP, userName, password);
            isSFTPConnected = sftpManager.connect(hostIP, userName, password);
            if(isSFTPConnected && isSShConnected){
                System.out.println("Connected");
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks fabian, sorry for such a lame post